# Series convergence of $\sum_1^\infty\frac{(n!)^2+(2n)^n}{n^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_1^\infty\frac{(n!)^2+(2n)^n}{n^{2n}}$$ 
Is there a way to test convergence of this series wihout splitting it ? (in case splitting is correct)

Comment: I deleted my answer because I do not answer the question about splitting. I apologize. Cheers :-)

Comment: Find out the order of the numerator: is $(n!)^2\ge (2n)^n$ in general?  Then you can compare the greatest of the two with the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show, using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), that for $n\ge10$, we have $0\le(2n)^n\le(n!)^2$, and then use squeezing.