# Does $\sum_1^\infty\frac{(n!)^2+(2n)^n}{n^{2n}}$ converge? (without Stirling's approximation)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This question have been asked again a long ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054293/series-convergence-of-sum-1-infty-fracn22nnn2n), but its only answer gives just a hint about Stirling's approximation.

I am trying to study the convergence  $\sum_1^\infty\frac{(n!)^2+(2n)^n}{n^{2n}}$, **but without Stirling's approximation.**

---

I tried Cauchy's condensation test with no luck. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20%20%5Cfrac%7B%28n%21%29%5E2%2B%282n%29%5En%7D%7Bn%5E%7B2n%7D%7D%20) suggests root test

The limit is:

$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{(n!)^2+(2n)^n}{n^{2n}}}$

Again [Wolfram calulates the limit to be:](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%28%28n%21%5E2+%2B+%282+n%29%5En%29%2Fn%5E%282+n%29%29%5E%281%2Fn%29) $e^{-2}$

Therefore, somehow $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(n!)^2+(2n)^n}{n^{2n}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}
 \left(1-\frac2{n}\right)^n$

but I have no idea how to prove that.

---

I don't want to reduce this question exclusively to the calculation of this limit, any answer that doesn't include Stirling's approximation is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What Stirling implies is that the numerator is dominated by the $n!^2$ term. So the question boils down to $(n!)^{1/n}/n\to e^{-1}$ which I suppose is a weak form of Stirling. You might be able to get this by applying the trapezium rule to $\int_1^n\ln x\,dx$ and using crude estimates.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354487/does-the-series-sum-n-nn-converge-or-diverge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that$$\require{cancel}\frac{\frac{(n+1)!^2}{(n+1)^{2(n+1)}}}{\frac{n!^2}{n^{2n}}}=\cancel{(n+1)^2}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n}\frac1{\cancel{(n+1)^2}}\to\frac1{e^2}$$and that$$\frac{\frac{(2(n+1))^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{2(n+1)}}}{\frac{(2n)^n}{n^{2n}}}=2(n+1)\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^{2n}\frac1{(n+1)^2}=\frac2{n+1}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n\to0.$$So, both series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!^2}{n^{2n}}\text{ and }\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n)^n}{n^{2n}}$$converge and therefore so does their sum.

Comment: just finished calculating exactly same. +1.

Comment: Note that $\sum_1^\infty\frac{(n!)^2+(2n)^n}{n^{2n}} < \sum_1^\infty\frac{(n!)^2}{n^{2n}}$, and visa versa hence, calculating only one limit is sufficient. Thank you!

Comment: How do you justify that inequality?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't, its wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Convergence of this series is quite easy. First note that $\sum \frac {(2n)^{n}} {n^{2n}}$ is convergent since it is dominated by $\frac {2^{n}} {3^{n}}$ if you omit the first two terms.
Now use the fact that $n! < (1)(2)(n^{n-2})$ for $n \geq 3$.  Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

We have that eventually, using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2681474/505767)

$$(n!)^2\ge \left(\frac{n^2}{e^2}\right)^n\ge(2n)^n$$

therefore

$$\frac{(n!)^2+(2n)^n}{n^{2n}}\le \frac{2(n!)^2}{n^{2n}}=2\frac{n!}{n^{n}}\frac{n!}{n^{n}} \le \frac2{n^2}$$

since

$$\frac{n!}{n^{n}}=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdots n}{n\cdot n\cdots n} \le \frac{1}{n}\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots 1 = \frac{1}{n}$$